# Подготовка данных из csv файла для обучения модели в scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Есть файл csv, содержащий данные в двух столбцах. В одном из них содержится категория "Positive", "Negative" или "Neytral". В другом столбце - некоторый набор слов "Bread Light Happyness". Данные целиком текстовые. Задача - преобразовать их в формат, пригодный для обучения классификатора. Я не ищу готового решения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чего можно начать? За исключением чтения данных из файла. Их я читаю так:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('~/projects/text_classifier/learm_ck.csv')
```

Comment: Больше спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположим у нас есть след. DataFrame:

```
In [74]: df
Out[74]:
                               Text  Category
0                      This is cool  Positive
1                      Lovely story  Positive
2             Wow, it is very good!  Positive
3                 The plot is awful  Negative
4                         Bad movie  Negative
5                      Not that bad   Neutral
6  Actors good, but plot is labored   Neutral
```

Преобразуем категорию в цифровое значение:

```
In [75]: df['cat_no'] = pd.Categorical(pd.factorize(df.Category)[0])

In [76]: df
Out[76]:
                               Text  Category cat_no
0                      This is cool  Positive      0
1                      Lovely story  Positive      0
2             Wow, it is very good!  Positive      0
3                 The plot is awful  Negative      1
4                         Bad movie  Negative      1
5                      Not that bad   Neutral      2
6  Actors good, but plot is labored   Neutral      2

In [77]: df.dtypes
Out[77]:
Text          object
Category      object
cat_no      category
dtype: object
```

Теперь "токенизируем" текст и преобразуем его в понятный для классификаторов вид:

```
#import nltk
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

vect = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5, analyzer='word', stop_words='english')
X = vect.fit_transform(df.Text)
r = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=vect.get_feature_names())
t = df[['Category','cat_no']].join(r)
```

Результат:

```
In [82]: t
Out[82]:
   Category cat_no    actors     awful       bad  cool      good   labored    lovely     movie      plot     story       wow
0  Positive      0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   1.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
1  Positive      0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.707107  0.000000  0.000000  0.707107  0.000000
2  Positive      0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   0.0  0.638709  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.769449
3  Negative      1  0.000000  0.769449  0.000000   0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.638709  0.000000  0.000000
4  Negative      1  0.000000  0.000000  0.638709   0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.769449  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
5   Neutral      2  0.000000  0.000000  1.000000   0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
6   Neutral      2  0.544082  0.000000  0.000000   0.0  0.451635  0.544082  0.000000  0.000000  0.451635  0.000000  0.000000
```

Comment: А если данные в файле разбиты разделителем (как их извлечь - понятно)? Когда столбца всего два (категории и текст для классификации), стало более понятно. Но если данные для классификации сами разделены, и в датафрейме получился двумерный массив, в котором категории расположены в нулевом столбце, как данные подготовить для "скармливания" классификатору? Пока решения не нашел.

Comment: @GlassedMichail, попробуйте открыть новый вопрос с __воспроизводимым__ примером ваших данных